# A Balanced Breakfast

Tags: lateral-thinking, language

An European mathematician likes to have a [balanced](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/balanced) breakfast every day.

It always includes whole milk and exactly one ingredient out of the list below:

- Butter
- Cheese
- Yoghurt

What is the mathematician's nationality?

Comment: Does he vary between those 3? Or is it always milk & butter f.ex?

Comment: I see the language tag here. Do we need any foreign language knowledge to answer?

Comment: Just want to point out how unbalanced any of those breakfasts would be

Answer (score 3):

A look in a thesaurus tells us that a synonym of 'balanced' is:

> 'EVENED'

This might mean that this mathematician prefers their breakfast to have:

> An **even number of letters** in total among its ingredients.

Since they use 'whole milk'...

> (which is 9 letters long) they will need to add another ingredient *with an odd number of letters* in order for the combined ingredients to have an even number of letters overall. The one ingredient on the list with an odd number of letters is **YOGHURT** (7 letters).

Since the mathematician is from a *European* country, this means they are most likely:

> **BRITISH**, since this is the common British spelling of a word often spelled 'yogurt' (without the 'H') in other parts of the English-speaking world.
>
>  (I think they could also be Irish - I'm not 100% of the spelling there - but since the UK has a much greater population (66m vs approx. 5m) by probability alone they are more likely to be British...)

Comment: The answer is unambigous.

Comment: I'd be a bit disappointed if this is it. Looks a bit random, and not very self-confirming. (Also, I didn't know yogurt vs yoghurt was a British/American thing?)

Comment: @Randal'Thor [This article](https://writingexplained.org/yogurt-vs-yoghurt-difference) gives a fairly nice balanced look at UK vs US. And I would query your use of 'random' when I've explained my step-by-step logic above! ;)

Comment: I mean, the question would be a bit random if this is the intended answer.